# Extraer valor de un objeto

Tags: javascript

Tengo una duda del millón, ¿existe la posibilidad de solo extraer los valores de un objeto (key) en javascript?

```
[
  {
    name: "Sucursal 1", 
    data:
    [
      {id: 1, usuarios: 3}, 
      {id: 2, usuarios: 0}, 
      {id: 3, usuarios: 5}, 
      {id: 3, usuarios: 2}
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Sucursal 2", 
    data:
    [
      {id: 1, usuarios: 9}, 
      {id: 2, usuarios: 10}, 
      {id: 3, usuarios: 4}, 
      {id: 3, usuarios: 3}
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Sucursal 3", 
    data:
    [
      {id: 1, usuarios: 0}, 
      {id: 2, usuarios: 1}, 
      {id: 3, usuarios: 3}, 
      {id: 3, usuarios: 4}
    ]
  }
]
```

Lo que intento construir a base de ese objecto es lo siguiente:

```
[
  {
    name: "Sucursal 1", 
    data: [3, 0, 5, 2]
  },
  {
    name: "Sucursal 2", 
    data: [9, 10, 4, 3]
  },
  {
    name: "Sucursal 3", 
    data: [ 0, 1, 3, 4]
  }
]
```

Intenté usando `push`, También intenté usando ForEach para recorrer el objeto, pero me perdí en el intento.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Puedes hacer dos `map()` anidados:

```js
const arr = [{name: "Sucursal 1",data:[{id: 1, usuarios:3},{id: 2, usuarios: 0},{id: 3, usuarios: 5},{id: 3, usuarios: 2}]},{name: "Sucursal 2",data:[{id: 1,usuarios: 9},{id: 2, usuarios: 10},{id: 3, usuarios: 4},{id: 3, usuarios: 3}]},{name: "Sucursal 3",data:[{id: 1, usuarios: 0},{id: 2, usuarios: 1},{id: 3, usuarios: 3},{id: 3, usuarios: 4}]}];



const res = arr.map(e=>{return {name:e.name,data:e.data.map(u=>u.usuarios)}});

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Genial, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 6):

Podés usar la función `reduce` para extraer únicamente los valores de `usuarios` dentro del arreglo de objetos `data`:

```js
var arregloOriginal = [
  {
    name: "Sucursal 1", 
    data:
    [
      {id: 1, usuarios: 3}, 
      {id: 2, usuarios: 0}, 
      {id: 3, usuarios: 5}, 
      {id: 3, usuarios: 2}
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Sucursal 2", 
    data:
    [
      {id: 1, usuarios: 9}, 
      {id: 2, usuarios: 10}, 
      {id: 3, usuarios: 4}, 
      {id: 3, usuarios: 3}
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Sucursal 3", 
    data:
    [
      {id: 1, usuarios: 0}, 
      {id: 2, usuarios: 1}, 
      {id: 3, usuarios: 3}, 
      {id: 3, usuarios: 4}
    ]
  }
];

console.log(arregloOriginal.map(e => {return {name: e.name,data: e.data.reduce((a,b) => [...a, b.usuarios], [])};}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Mi opción para este problema sería usar _ Underscore:

```
console.log(_.map(data3, x=>SeleccionaValoresArreglo(x) ));

function SeleccionaValoresArreglo(data){
   data.data = _.map(data.data,x=>x.usuarios);
   return data;
}
```

Separado en dos funciones para mejorar la legibilidad, solo pon en SeleccionaValoresArreglo(x) tu arreglo original.
No regresa otro arreglo, sino solo modifica la parte necesaria.